# Combine pageLoad() code from user control?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have main `default.aspx` page which used to have the following `Javascript` in it:

```
function pageLoad()
    {
        fUpdateFavoriteImageIfNeeded();
        fJGPSSet();          
    }
```

Now though I have a new user control `UserControlFavoriteUpdate.ascx` and want to have the following in it so that any page that has the user control control embedded in it also gets that `Javascript` included:

```
  function pageLoad()
        {
            fUpdateFavoriteImageIfNeeded();                         
        }
```

It seems that if the calling page ends up having two `pageLoad()` functions listed in it's `Javascript` it only runs the last one.

How can I combine the user-control's `pageLoad()` code into the calling page's `pageLoad()`? In the worst case I can manually put that line in the calling page code but was hoping to keep it all within the `UserControlFavoriteUpdate.ascx` in case someone else embedded that control in a page and didn't realize it needed that `pageLoad()` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding a load script in the `Page_Load()` method in the back page of your user control to avoid duplicate methods within the same scope.

Something like:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Me.[GetType](), 
    "LoadScript", 
    "Sys.Application.add_load(function() { fUpdateFavoriteImageIfNeeded(); });", 
    True);
```

Comment: Thank you. I plan to test your code next week and can mark it as an answer then.